# How does generic type work in Scala?

Tags: list, scala

I was very surprised by the fact that we can assign List[Nothing] To any list. Like this

```
val nums : List[Number] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val nums_2 : List[Integer] = Nil; // <--- extends List[Nothing]
val ints : List[Integer] = nums  // error: type mismatch
```

So, this is very confusing. In [this article](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Nothing.html) they said that

> Because lists are covariant in Scala, this makes
>   scala.collection.immutable.Nil an instance of `List[T]`, for any element
>   of type `T`.

What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: See https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance and http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Nothing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a generic type is covariant in a given type parameter (denoted by a `+` before that type parameter in the type's definition, like `abstract class List[+T]`), that means that if you have two types `T` and `U`, such that `T` is a subtype of `U`, `List[T]` is also a subtype of `List[U]`.

So a variable that's supposed to hold a `List[Any]` can also hold a `List[String]` because `String` is a subtype of `Any` and a variable that's supposed to hold a `List[Whatever]` can also hold a `List[Nothing]` because `Nothing` is a subtype of every type (it's kinda magical in that regard).

Comment: Got it, the key thing is that is's immutable. Thank you.

Comment: The key thing is that the `List[T]` type constructor is covariant in `T`. The reason that is type-safe is that `List[T]` is immutable. In general: if you can only read from it, it's safe to be covariant (e.g. `List[T]`). If you can only write to it, it's safe to be contravariant (e.g. `Logger[T]`). If you can both read and write, it's unsafe to be either co- or contravariant, it must be invariant. (See Java's arrays which are mutable but covariant, and what do we get? `ArrayStoreException`.) That's why `FunctionN[-T1, -T2, -T3, …, +R]` is contravariant in its parameter types and covariant in …

Comment: … its return type.